# Nginx : ioctl(FIONBIO) worker_socket bind failed

Tags: nginx, centos6, server-administration

I have setup Nginx in my local Lab environment for rtmp testing. initially, I was working fine. But all of sudden its stopped working . I don't know why. After searching the logs, I found this error message. Can anyone help me on

Debug Error Log:

> 2015/01/31 22:51:13 [debug] 12127#0: auto_push: creating sockets
>   2015/01/31 22:51:13 [debug] 12127#0: auto_push: create socket
>   '/var/sock/nginx-rtmp.0' 2015/01/31 22:51:13 [debug] 12127#0:
>   auto_push: delete existing socket '/var/sock/nginx-rtmp.0' 2015/01/31
>   22:51:13 [emerg] 12127#0: ioctl(FIONBIO) worker_socket bind failed (2:
>   No such file or directory) 2015/01/31 22:51:13 [notice] 12125#0:
>   signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received 2015/01/31 22:51:13 [notice] 12125#0:
>   worker process 12127 exited with code 2 2015/01/31 22:51:13 [alert]
>   12125#0: worker process 12127 exited with fatal code 2 and cannot be
>   respawned 2015/01/31 22:51:13 [debug] 12125#0: shmtx forced unlock

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. as the socket creation folder doesn't have a write permission for nginx. Error gone Once I set the privileges.

Thanks.